# Циклы while и for в Bash

Tags: linux, bash, for, while

Есть задание: вывести числа от 0 до 100, которые делятся на три.
Для задачи использовать циклы while или for.
Я додумался до двух вариантов:

```
for ((i=3; i<100; i+=3)); do  
echo $i  
done
```

и

```
i=3  
while [[ $i -le 100 ]]; do  
echo $i  
i=$(($i+3))  
done
```

Подозреваю, что еще есть что-то связанное с умножением или делением, но в голову ничего не лезет.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Не понятно что вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `man seq` должно помочь, и никакого цикла не надо.

Answer (score 2):

вот еще парочку вариантов:

```
for i in {3..99..3};do echo $i;done

for i in {1..100};do (( $i%3 == 0 )) && echo $i;done
```

Comment: А можно нескромную просьбу расшифровать `{3..99..3}`?

Comment: `for i in {1..100};{(($i%3))||echo $i;}`

Comment: @Krad диапазон чисел от 3 до 99 с шагом 3

Comment: Просто вывести цифры можно `echo {3..100..3}` цикл для печати лишний

Comment: @ipatev_nn конечно можно, но ведь в задании написанно - _"Для задачи использовать циклы while или for."_

Comment: @Zt. точно, я не так прочел вопрос))